# Why does the following produce an error?

Tags: ms-access, precision

I am trying to insert a value of **12,500,000.00** into an Access table and receive the following error message:

> Decimal fields precision is too small to accept the numeric you attempted to add.

The field in the table is of data type Number and has the following properties:

- Precision 19
- Scale 14
- Decimal Places 5

I don't understand because 12,500,000.00 has a precision of 8 and scale of 2. And decimal places is for display purposes only, not storage.

I fixed it by changing precision to 25, but would still appreciate some clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Precision :**  *The total number of digits that can be stored, both to the left and right of the decimal point*

**Scale :**     *The maximum number of digits that can be stored to the right of the decimal separator*

**Decimal Places :** *The number of digits that are displayed the right of the decimal separator*

In other words, by using a precision of 19, you were declaring your field to have 5 digits to the left of the decimal point, and 14 to the right (the value of **Scale**).

Changing the total precision to 25, allows 11 digits to be able to be stored to the left of the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

A `decimal` is a fixed-point number and when you set a scale of 14, there are actually 14 digits (in your case, zeroes) reserved right side of the decimal point. The scale is part of the precision.

It is different from what you expect in floating-point numbers when you can write `12,500,000.00` as `1.25e+7` and you have a precision of 3.